# boost serialization data type compatibility

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, cross-platform

I need to serialize/deserialize certain data structures between two identical applications, but built using different compilers.

Consider primitive datatypes. Boost documentation mentions that in order to ensure compatibility you need to use the numeric types in `<boost/cstdint.hpp>`. So did I understand it right that I can't simply declare `int number;`, but rather I should do something like `int16_t number;`?

Comment: Yes, if you need to have maximum compatibility. If you have c++11, then the language provides cross compatible types for you like int32_t / uint64_t etc.

Comment: Cross-compiler compatibilty: yes but don't forget about endianness

Comment: @Christophe I see. I suppose the endianness issue pertains only to native binary archives (for example, boost::archive::binary_oarchive), is that so? I appreciate your timely responses.

Comment: @MutomboDikey yes for native binary only. Portable binary is ok. Text archiver doesn't have endianness issues (unless you have unions or bitfields in your struct that would make implicit assumptions on endianness).